# Split an array in half and find the two Max values and then merge the two values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm taking an online class so there isn't any help from the teachers or other classmates. Our assignment is that we need to find the max value and index of an array of random numbers. We need to do it in two ways. A regualr loop(brute force) and divide and conquer. In the divide and conquer we need to split the array into two smaller arrays and find the max of both and then merge.

I got the brute force to work and I got the divide and conqure to find the max also. But I can't seem to get the max of the two smaller arrays and merge the two. We also need to check for how many comparison is made by both methods and print the output.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  public class MinMaxValues{  



 // Find maxiumum (largest) value in array using Divide and Conquer


 public static int findMax( int[]numbers, int left, int right )
 {
 int middle;
 int max_l, max_r, max_m;

 if ( left == right )    // Only one element...
 {  
    // Base case: solved easily...

    return numbers[left];
 }
 else
 {

    // Solve smaller problems

    middle = (left+right)/2;   // Divide into 2 halves

    max_l = findMax( numbers, left, middle);  
               // Find max in first half 

    max_r = findMax( numbers, middle+1, right);  
               // Find max in second half
      //System.out.println("Maximum Value = " + max_r);   
    max_m = max_l+ max_r;

    // Use the solutions to solve original problem

    if ( max_l > max_r )
       return(max_l);
    else
       return(max_r);
          //return(max_m);

  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: I would remove the code you are not using (the add) What exactly is the problem? Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: It looks correct to me.  Why do you say it is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge the two'? Do you mean put the two arrays together that you just split up?

Comment: It looks correct. The only point of possible confusion is that `max_m` is not used -- you don't need it.

Comment: Is `max_m` part of "We also need to check for how many comparison is made by both methods and print the output."?  Then that part is wrong.

Comment: `return Arrays.sort(numbers)[numbers.length - 1];`

Comment: I think he means use `Math.max(left_max, right_max)` to merge two maximums.

Comment: What's correct with above is that It's giving me the max value using both brute and divide and conquer. I also have to get the index of the brute value. What I'm not getting in the divide and conquer algo. is the max value of each side. Once I get the max value after it splits I'm suppose to add the two max values. I'm supposed to print the two separate max values and then print the sum of the two added together.  Thanks so much for your help so far.

Comment: Looking at findMax, I see that you are checking `left == right` but what you might also want to do is to check `if(right-left == 1)` At this point you only have 2 elements left, find the max among those and  you should have max_l on the left side and max_r on the right side. Then you can print them and also get the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You are never returning an array.

Also you don't make any changes to the array.

You must change the array in some way once you find the max.

Try wrapping it with  a method.

```
   public static int[] maxSort(int[] array,int length){
   int[] sorted = new int[array.length];
   sorted[arrayLength]=findmax(array,0,sorted,arrayLength);//assumes find max returns                         maximum value of entire array.
   while(length>0){
   sorted=maxsort(array,length--);
   }
   return sorted;
   }
```

I am not 100% sure it's working by i think it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to more carefully address points in your program where you are comparing the index or the value at that index.  For example, instead of checking whether `max_l > max_r`, I believe you mean to be checking whether `numbers[max_l] > numbers[max_r]`.